# If this one is too hard, you can always take a pass on it

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

So many possibilities!

> What does this represent?

[image]

What do we have here?
Hint:

> Four red 4-sided polygons and four *blue* polygons, for a total of 32 lines and 32 vertices
> (16 blue, 16 red).
>  Does this help?

Comment: reverse image search shows that the background is a stock image of leather, but also images of footballs show up. good starting point? and given that in the title it says "you can always take a pass on it," seems like football might be relevant...

Comment: Football and trypophobia :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> The polygons represent NFL divisions - the red ones represent NFC divisions, and the blue ones represent AFC divisions.  Each point on a polygon represents a team in that division.
>
> [image]